Can I use Prophet on a timeseries with a nonstationary daily variation?
I have some temperature data with gaps that I need to interpolate onto a uniform time series (and extrapolate a bit too). I am trying to use FB Prophet and it seems almost perfect. And yet....
If you look at the graph you can see that if the missing data is far from a daily extreme then Prophet is fine. But when the missing data is near an daily max/min then it ignores the measured data.

Reading the documentation it seems that Prophet anticipates data of the form a(t) + F(H) where t is daily time, a(t) is slowly varying but nonstationary, H is the hourly time and F(H) is the periodic variation for that day, but it does not anticipate a(t) + b(t) F(H) where b is also slowly varying but nonstationary.
I see in Adaptive Normalization for Non-stationary Time
Series Forecasting: that those authors decompose each day into slices and then apply normalization by removing and restores the non-stationary factors a(t) and b(t). Would that be the correct approach here? It doesnt seem completely trivial to implement because they use machine learning to do the splicing and dicing.
Alternatively,  I do see that Prophet allows introduction of arbitrary regressors. If I somehow estimated b(t) (e.g. by averaging each day), or whatever, then is there a way to tell Prophet about b?
How else do people interpolate gaps in time series? This seems like it should be a completely standard problem to solve, but I'm stumbling.
df_p =  df[["Time","Temperature"]].copy()
df_p = df_p.rename(columns={"Time":"ds", "Temperature": "y"})

model = Prophet(changepoint_prior_scale=0.1)
model.fit(df_p.dropna())
end  = end=df_p['ds'].iloc[-1] + pd.Timedelta(1,"d")
uniform_dates = pd.date_range(start=df_p['ds'].iloc[0], end=end, freq='15T')
uniform_df = pd.DataFrame({'ds': uniform_dates})

#
# Fill in the values
#
forecast = model.predict(uniform_df)

plt.plot(df_p["ds"],df_p["y"],'o',markersize=1)
plt.plot(forecast["ds"], forecast["yhat"])
plt.show()


Some discussion on this here: https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/234

This is the best that I have so far. I do rolling max and min with 1D window and then smooth that using filtfilt so as to not introduce any phase error.

I then linearly shift the data:
df["y"] = (df["data"] - 0.5*(df["max_data"]+df["min_data"]))/(df["max_data"]-df["min_data"))

Apply Prophet to that, and linearly shift back:

That captures the data better than I had before. Prophet still seems to not be excited about believing the max/min temperature values though.
On the plus, side I now can get completely reasonable looking temperatures even with many days missing. In plot below, I nulled out all of the data in the middle of the data set but then linearly interpolate max and min and apply above algorithm, which gives:


For a further tweak I just added: model.add_seasonality(name='daily', period=1, fourier_order=10) which helped a little.
